# dplyr apply a single function with changing argument to the same column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a simple df with one column, and I want to create multiple new columns using a single function (`sum_x` in this case) with only an argument changing. Is there a way to do this more efficiently than the way I have shown below in `dplyr`? Ideally I could incorporate `sum_vec` and do this in a single line to create 100 new columns. This seems to be a very simple problem, but I don't know how to solve this efficiently using `dplyr`.

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:20)
sum_x <- function(x, y){
 x + y
}

sum_vec <- 1:100
df %>% mutate(x_1 = sum_x(x, 1)) %>% mutate(x_2 = sum_x(x, 2)) %>% mutate(x_3 = sum_x(x, 3))
```

Answer (score 1):

try it this way

```
library(tidyverse)
bind_cols(df, map_dfc(1:3, ~ df %>% transmute(!!paste0("x_", .x) := x + .x)))

    x x_1 x_2 x_3
1   1   2   3   4
2   2   3   4   5
3   3   4   5   6
4   4   5   6   7
5   5   6   7   8
6   6   7   8   9
7   7   8   9  10
8   8   9  10  11
9   9  10  11  12
10 10  11  12  13
11 11  12  13  14
12 12  13  14  15
13 13  14  15  16
14 14  15  16  17
15 15  16  17  18
16 16  17  18  19
17 17  18  19  20
18 18  19  20  21
19 19  20  21  22
20 20  21  22  23
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like `for` loop, I am with you. So I'm not sure if this is good/efficient. Interested in a better solution.

```
library(dplyr)

for (i in 1:100) {
  x_header = paste("x", i, sep = "_")
  df = df %>% 
    mutate(!!x_header := sum_x(x, i))
}
```

```
> df[1:11, 1:11]
    x x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4 x_5 x_6 x_7 x_8 x_9 x_10
1   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10   11
2   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11   12
3   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12   13
4   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13   14
5   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14   15
6   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15   16
7   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16   17
8   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17   18
9   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18   19
10 10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19   20
11 11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20   21
```